# Is there a way to get this session id using only javascript?

Tags: javascript, spring, session

I am developing a spring MVC based Java Application.
When you open a browser window, a session id is created.
on the server side we can get the session id, something as follows

```
httpServletRequest.getSession().getId()
```

Is there a way to get this session id using only javascript? I mean in the client side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the session id to an hidden html field at your html and than get value of this field by using javascript

Answer (score 2):

Considering you want to use only javascript:There is no such solution.
The reason is javascript is executed on your browser and your session on the server.

But you can make use of the following after assigning somevalue to `var my_session`

**jquery.cookie.js** : https://raw.github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/master/jquery.cookie.js

This is a nice small library for storing data in cookies.

Refer this fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/fhe27/3/

---

```
var my_session="123456789";
$.cookie('session_id',my_session);//drop a cookie
```

---

```
var my_session = $.cookie('session_id');//read a cookie
```

Otherwise,the soultion provided by @samir turgay is also decent.

Answer (score 1):

```
var strCookies = document.cookie;
var cookiearray = strCookies.split(';')
for(var i=0; i<cookiearray.length; i++){
  name = cookiearray[i].split('=')[0];
  value = cookiearray[i].split('=')[1];
  if(name == 'sid')
   sid = value;
}
```

if you google you will get it

Answer (score 1):

You can define js variable like this

```
var jsessionId = '${cookie.JSESSIONID.value}';
```